# Understanding an example of LZW decompression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, compression, lzw

I'm trying to understand this example of decompression using the LZW algorithm.

I would like to undestand why we insert `ba` in row 4; we're currently at `i=3`, so the index `s=ab` as shown in row 3; we previously had `a` and `b` so aren't we supposed to look for `abab` in the dictionary? So why is the result `ba` and not `abba`?

[image: [1]: http://hpics.li/6ae07fa "LZW decompression"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the English version of Wikipedia: "Buffer input characters in a sequence ω until ω + next character is not in the dictionary. Emit the code for ω, and add ω + next character to the dictionary. Start buffering again with the next character."